# PHP - sum values except one in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sum

This is what we have, as I understand this is a complex array:

```
<?php
// the elements array var_dump($elements);

$elements = array(4) {
[0]=> object(stdClass) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["velocity"]=> string(3) "500" } //this is element0
[1]=> object(stdClass) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["velocity"]=> string(3) "600" } //this is element1
[2]=> object(stdClass) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["velocity"]=> string(3) "700" } //this is element2
[3]=> object(stdClass) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["velocity"]=> string(3) "800" } //this is element3
}

// the foreach

$sumAll=0; 
foreach ($elements as $key=>$element) {
$trek = $element->velocity; 

$someVarINeed = ( $key == 0 ) ? $external_value : $sumAll + $trek[$key-1]; // this is what I know it would work but it does not


// EXPECTED RESULTS

//because there is no previous 
when $key=0 $someVarINeed = $external_value;

// this should be $someVarINeed = 0 + 500 = 500
when $key=1 $someVarINeed = $sumAll + $element0->velocity;

// this should be $someVarINeed = 0 + 500 + 600 = 1100
when $key=2 $someVarINeed = $sumAll + $element0->velocity + $element1->velocity; 

// this should be $someVarINeed = 0 + 500 + 600 + 700 = 1800
when $key=3 $someVarINeed = $sumAll + $element0->velocity + $element1->velocity + $element2->velocity; 
}
?>
```

I edited the code I hope makes more sense.

I don't know if this is an object/array whatever, I want to sum up the values of $trek to be used for each $element as a value only determined by the sum of the previous elements values and not itself.

As always, thanks for any reply :)

Comment: That's not a valid array; your foreach does not reference an array in the script you provided (maybe you meant foreach $var?); Don't use the variable name of the array value from the current loop the same as the array name; Use `=` to set a variable to a value, not to check it.

Comment: I am no coder really, I really don't know, I only know it works somehow, it sums up all the values including the last, the one I want to skip.

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. Your array declaration isn't quite right. I suggest you start by reading the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Danny - that would do nothing as the array name $vars on your foreach doesn't exist. you;d just get a php warning "$vars is not an array" (or whatever)

Comment: Also, I *think* this is what you want: 

    `$array = array( 
    array("my_value" => 500),
    array("my_value", 700),
    );`

Comment: sorry, editing your code to add "I'm no coder" doesn't help us help you. Not being harsh, but as it is your code has lots of potential to fail, crash and return PHP warnings and errors. Get your code straitened out as per the comments and the answer, and we'll be able to help :)

Comment: I don't know, I think you are right, I've edited the question, please help me.

Comment: OK I will edit the code again, exactly as I have it.

Comment: Your last paragraph and therefore actual requirement is still unclear. Re word it and don't be afraid to write a bit more. While far too much is not good, a bit too much is better than not enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$trek is a value, it's not an array so you can't use $trek[$key-1].

Change it to: $elements[$key-1]->velocity

Comment: Thanks Don, awesome as always :)

Answer (score 0):

We are quite confused with your code since there are some unknown params and no proper array declaration.

Since you have mentioned...

> I want to sum up the values of $trek to be used for each $element as a
>   value only determined by the sum of the previous elements values and
>   not itself.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Code :

```
<?php
$elements=array(10,20,30); //An array with elements , keys not explicitly mentioned
$sumAll=0;
$someVarINeed=0;
$external_value=0;
foreach ($elements as $key=>$value) {
    $trek = $value;
    $someVarINeed += (( $key === 0 ) ? $external_value : $sumAll + $trek);
}
echo $someVarINeed;

?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

> 50

Since , we check `$key === 0` , the first array element has the key 0, so it will be assigned the `$external_value`. The following successive elements doesn't meet the condition as keys will 1 & 2. So the first element will be ignored and thus summing up the last 2 elements.

If you replace this array `$elements=array(10,20,30);` with `$elements=array('number1'=>10,'number2'=>20,'number3'=>30);` then the output will be **60**. As you can see all the values have keys assigned.

Comment: With your code example, the output should be 30, as a sum of 10 and 20.

Answer (score -2):

I think you accidentally an = in your test here:

```
if ( $key = 0 ) {
```

I think you meant:

```
if ( $key == 0 ) {
```

Comment: Or, maybe, `===`...? There is a lot more wrong in this code than that, however.